# Physical disk block size on POSIX using C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, filesystems, posix

I'm working on a high performance I/O program and I'm trying to find the best way to determine the `_physical_` (and not the `_logical_`) byte size of a device's disk blocks with C++. My research so far has led me to the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // file information including block size of the device
    struct stat info;
    // device to get block size from
    char * device = "/mnt/hdb1";

    if (stat(device, &info))
    {
        printf("stat() error");
        strerror(errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Prefered block size for '%s' is %i byte\n", device, info.st_blksize);
    return 0;
}
```

The man pages says the following about `st_blksize`:

> The st_blksize field gives the "preferred" blocksize for efficient
> file system I/O.  (Writing to a file in smaller chunks may cause an
> inefficient read-modify-rewrite.)

, but it does not mention if `st_blksize` is the logical or the physical disk block size.

So, is `st_blksize` the *physical* disk block size, and if so, then is this the most POSIX OS portable way of detecting the physical disk block size.

Comment: I don't think it's possible through POSIX.

Comment: I wonder what `st_blksize` is for `/dev/null`. And I wonder if that would be the *physical* size or the *logical* size.

Comment: @DanMoulding `/dev/null` is a character device, not a block device.

Comment: @Petesh: Can you point me to where in the POSIX standard this distinction is made?

Comment: @DanMoulding that would be in the `stat` `st_mode` field. That's about all POSIX has to say about what the difference is between a character and block special device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote an answer, that while hopeful did not work correctly for block devices.

There is no POSIX mechanism for obtaining the fundamental physical block size of a device, you will have to resort to `ioctl`, which is platform dependent.

For linux there's [`ioctl(fd, BLKPBSZGET, &block_size)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/ioctl.c#L367)

For Solaris there's the [`dkio`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2254/dkio-7i/index.html) interface, which allows you to get the physical block size.

```
dk_minfo_ext media_info;
if (-1 != ioctl(fd, DKIOMEDIAINFOEXT, &media_info))
    block_size = media_info.dki_pbsize;
```

For Mac OS X, it's [`ioctl(fd, DKIOCGETPHYSICALBLOCKSIZE, &block_size)`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/disk.h).

For FreeBSD, it should be [`iotcl(fd, DIOCGSECTORSIZE, &block_size)`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/disk.h#L28).

Comment: What about `ioctl(fd, FIGETBSZ, &block_size)` ? Is `FIGETBSZ` also the _physical_ blocksize?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Nope, it's the size of blocks for a file system in terms of the file system's block allocation strategy

Comment: And on Windows GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() :)

Comment: @CesarOrtiz You would need to use the [Virtual Disk Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986750(v=vs.85).aspx), which allows determining the block size of a disk; as for other block devices; I don't know

Comment: @CesarOrtiz No, that will only get the _logical_ blocksize on Windows, you need to do a `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` storage query with `DeviceIoControl()`: `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storageQuery; storageQuery.PropertyId = StorageAccessAlignmentProperty; storageQuery.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery; STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR diskAlignment = {0}; DeviceIoControl(hDrive, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &storageQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY), &diskAlignment, sizeof(STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR), &outsize, NULL); std::cout<<diskAlignment.BytesPerPhysicalSector;`