# how to properly use posix_memalign

Tags: c, posix

I'am struggling to find out how to proper use the pread and pwrite. 
In this case, I am trying to read only 256 bytes using pread.
However, that whenever I try to read less than 512 bytes pread will not return anything. 
I believe that this problem has to be with the SECTOR argument that I am assigning to posix_memalign...

Is there some obvious info that I have to be aware of?

```
#define BUF_SIZE 256
#define SECTOR 512
#define FILE_SIZE 1024 * 1024 * 1024 //1G


int main( int argc, char **argv ){

    int fd, nr;
    char fl_nm[]={"/dev/nvme0n1p1"};

    char* aligned_buf_w = NULL;
    char* aligned_buf_r = NULL;

    void* ad = NULL;
    if (posix_memalign(&ad, SECTOR, BUF_SIZE)) {
        perror("posix_memalign failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    aligned_buf_w = (char *)(ad);


    ad = NULL;
    if (posix_memalign(&ad, SECTOR, BUF_SIZE)) {
        perror("posix_memalign failed"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    aligned_buf_r = (char *)(ad);

    memset(aligned_buf_w, '*', BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    printf("BEFORE READ BEGIN\n");
    printf("\t aligned_buf_w::%ld\n",strlen(aligned_buf_w));
    printf("\t aligned_buf_r::%ld\n",strlen(aligned_buf_r));
    printf("BEFORE READ END\n");


    fd = open(fl_nm, O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
    pwrite(fd, aligned_buf_w, BUF_SIZE, 0);


    //write error checking
    if(nr == -1){
        perror("[error in write 2]\n");
    }


    nr = pread(fd, aligned_buf_r, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    //read error checking
    if(nr == -1){
        perror("[error in read 2]\n");
    }


    printf("AFTER READ BEGIN\n");
    printf("\taligned_buf_r::%ld \n",strlen(aligned_buf_r));
    printf("AFTER READ END\n");


    //error checking for close process
    if(close(fd) == -1){
        perror("[error in close]\n");
    }else{
        printf("[succeeded in close]\n");
    }


    return  0;
}
```

Here is the output when I read and write 512 bytes

```
BEFORE READ BEGIN
         aligned_buf_w::512
         aligned_buf_r::0
BEFORE READ END
AFTER READ BEGIN
        aligned_buf_r::512 
AFTER READ END
[succeeded in close]
```

and here is the result when I try to read 256 bytes

```
BEFORE READ BEGIN
         aligned_buf_w::256
         aligned_buf_r::0
BEFORE READ END
[error in read 2]
: Invalid argument
AFTER READ BEGIN
        aligned_buf_r::0 
AFTER READ END
[succeeded in close]
```

Comment: You're carefully checking whether `posix_memalign` and `close` failed, but you're not checking at all whether `open`, `pwrite`, and `pread` failed. Add code to check for failure of _all_ system calls.  If you still don't know what's wrong after running the program with that change, tell us exactly what it printed.  If `pread` and `pwrite` are succeeding, I want to know the actual number that they are returning.

Comment: Although `FILE_SIZE` is not used, `#define FILE_SIZE 1024 * 1024 * 1024 //1G` will likely cause problems with the `//` comment.  Recommend `#define FILE_SIZE (1024 * 1024 * 1024 /*1G*/)`

Comment: (You're accessing a block device, and you're using `O_DIRECT`, so it's possible that you just plain _can't_ read or write fewer than 512 bytes at a time.  But that has nothing to do with the alignment of the user-space buffer, and you should have gotten an actual error from `pread` if that was happening.)

Comment: @zwol thanks for advice, I have added the return value for pread and pwrite they both don't have any errors. The problem is I cannot read anything when I am using 256 byte. So According to your info is this not possible when I am using raw block device?

Comment: @SunghoHong *is this not possible when I am using raw block device?* Not on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using O_DIRECT "the kernel will do DMA directly from/to the physical memory pointed by the userspace buffer passed as parameter" - https://www.ukuug.org/events/linux2001/papers/html/AArcangeli-o_direct.html - so you have to observe some restrictions - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/raw.8.html

> All I/Os must be correctly aligned in memory and on disk: they must start at a sector
>          offset on disk, they must be an exact number of sectors long, and the
>          data buffer in virtual memory must also be aligned to a multiple of
>          the sector size.  The sector size is 512 bytes for most devices.

With buffered IO you do not care of that. The following sample illustrates that while reading a HDD (/dev/sda9) :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SECTOR 512

int main( int argc, char **argv ){

int fd, nr, BUF_SIZE;
char fl_nm[]={"/dev/sda9"};
char* buf = NULL;

if (argc>1) {
    BUF_SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);

    // BUFFERED IO
    printf("Buffered IO -------\n");
    if ((buf = (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE)) == NULL) perror("[malloc]");
    else {
        if ((fd = open(fl_nm, O_RDONLY)) == -1) perror("[open]");

        if((nr = pread(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 4096)) == -1) perror("[pread]");
        else
            printf("%i bytes read %.2x %.2x ...\n",nr,buf[0],buf[1]);

        free(buf);

        if(close(fd) == -1) perror("[close]");
    }

    // DIRECT IO
    printf("Direct IO ---------\n");
    if (posix_memalign((void *)&buf, SECTOR, BUF_SIZE)) {
        perror("posix_memalign failed");
    }
    else {
        if ((fd = open(fl_nm, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT)) == -1) perror("[open]");

        /* buf size , buf alignment and offset has to observe hardware restrictions */
        if((nr = pread(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 4096)) == -1) perror("[pread]");
        else
            printf("%i bytes read %.2x %.2x ...\n",nr,buf[0],buf[1]);

        free(buf);

        if(close(fd) == -1) perror("[close]");
    }
}

return  0;
}
```

You can verify the following behaviour :

```
$ sudo ./testodirect 512
Buffered IO -------
512 bytes read 01 04 ...
Direct IO ---------
512 bytes read 01 04 ...
$ sudo ./testodirect 4
Buffered IO -------
4 bytes read 01 04 ...
Direct IO ---------
[pread]: Invalid argument
```

By the way O_DIRECT is not in flavour of everybody https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/o_direct.html

Comment: The direct IO rant at https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/o_direct.html is horribly misinformed.  There are many use-cases where bypassing the page cache can be a huge performance benefit.  Just because his own kernel has a poor direct IO implementation that can't handle misaligned accesses nor smaller-than-page size/block size IO operations reliably is not a reason to trash the entire idea.  Sometimes caching really is a bad idea.  And you don't have to use asynchronous IO to get benefits from direct IO.

Comment: And yes, that rant is **misinformed**.  Torvalds posted "The thing that has always disturbed me about O_DIRECT is that the whole
interface is just stupid, and was probably designed by a deranged monkey
on some serious mind-controlling substances [\*]." and footnoted that with "[\*] In other words, it's an Oracleism."  That is just blatantly wrong.  Proper, working, stable, reliable direct IO existed by Solaris 8 - so it's from **Sun**, not Oracle.  And Sun's engineers were the creators of such things as NFS.

Comment: In fact, using Sun's (now Oracle's) high-performance QFS file system in shared mode **requires** the use of direct IO in order to avoid data corruption.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0262/gcrpx/index.html

Answer (score 3):

512B is the smallest unit you can read from a storage device

Comment: To get the exact block size for a given device, there is an ioctl. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947809/5382650